# How to select 'product' rows instead of 'sale' rows

Tags: c#, .net, linq

In my LINQ query below I want to select the 'product' rows and add the 'sale' rows data into it but the opposite is happening, it's selecting the 'sale' rows and adding the 'product' rows

```
var query = (from product in SampleProductTable
from sale in SampleSalesTable
where (sale.ProductId == product.Id)
select new
{
    Id = product.Id,
    TotalSales = product.TotalSales + ((product.Id == sale.ProductId) ? sale.Amount : 0)
})
```

**Sample Product Table**

```
+-------+------------+---------+-----------------+-------+------------+
|  Id   | CategoryId | BrandId |      Name       | Price | TotalSales |
+-------+------------+---------+-----------------+-------+------------+
| mlk3  | MLK        | BRND1   | Creamy Milk     |     5 |         10 |
| snck2 | SNCK       | BRND2   | Chocolate Snack |     2 |         24 |
+-------+------------+---------+-----------------+-------+------------+
```

**Sample Sales Table**

```
+-----+-----------+--------+
| Id  | ProductId | Amount |
+-----+-----------+--------+
| 120 | mlk3      |     55 |
| 121 | mlk3      |     15 |
| 122 | snck2     |     12 |
| 123 | mlk3      |      5 |
| 124 | mlk3      |     10 |
| 125 | snck2     |      2 |
| 126 | mlk3      |    115 |
| 127 | snck2     |      6 |
| 128 | snck2     |     34 |
+-----+-----------+--------+
```

**Desired Output**

```
+-------+------------+
|  Id   | TotalSales |
+-------+------------+
| mlk3  |        210 |
| snck2 |         78 |
+-------+------------+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var answer = (from product in SampleProductTable
              join sale in SampleSalesTable on product.Id == sale.ProductId into subSales
              from subSale in subSales.DefaultIfEmpty()
              group subSale by new { product.Id, product.TotalSales } into gr
              select new 
              {
                  gr.Key.Id,
                  TotalSales = gr.Sum(x => x == null ? 0 : x.Amount) + gr.Key.TotalSales
              }).ToList();
```

Approximate T-SQL:

```
select p.Id, p.TotalSales + sum(coalesce(s.Amount, 0)) TotalSales 
from SampleProductTable p
left outer join SampleSalesTable s on p.Id = s.ProductId 
group by p.Id, p.TotalSales
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll test this is as soon as I can.

Comment: I'm getting error in `group new sale by new` I'll try to convert your sql to linq and see if it works when I have time. thanks

Comment: @klent, sorry it's typo try `group sale by new` instead of `group new sale by new`

Comment: I'm still getting the `sale rows`

Comment: @klent, change `sale` to `subSale`

Answer (score 1):

In your example you join two collections the way that the result will have as many rows as there are distinct child records (sales in this case) and create a new object for each record (similar to INNER JOIN). That's why the result is "sales-based".

If I understand your intent correctly, I would approach it like:

```
SampleProductTable.Select(p => new 
{
    Id = p.Id,
    TotalSales = p.Sales.Sum(s => s.Amount)
}
```

please note that for this approach you will need to map "Sales" collection on a product.

Answer (score 1):

First of all it would be better to use the `join` statement instead, and then, it seems you need to group your `Sales` tables based on the `ProductId`:

```
 var query = (from product in SampleProductTable
              join sale in SampleSalesTable.GroupBy(c => c.ProductId) 
              on product.Id equals sale.Key
              select new
              {
                  Id = product.Id,
                  TotalSales = product.TotalSales + sale.Sum(c=>c.Amount)
              }).ToList();
```

Also please note: since you used a `where` statement in your code, you don't need to use this condition `(product.Id == sale.ProductId) ?` in your `select` anymore. Same as mine, because I used the join statement with `on` keyword, there is no need to use the condition in the select area.

You can see your desired result in the following link:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/RFTtrv

Answer (score 1):

In general LINQ terms the query shape you are looking for is called [grouped join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-grouped-joins):

> The group join is useful for producing hierarchical data structures. It pairs each element from the first collection with a set of correlated elements from the second collection.

In your case, it will produce a collection of correlated `Sales` for each `Product`. Then all you need is to apply aggregate (`Sum`) inside the final projection (`select`):

```
var query =
    from product in SampleProductTable
    join sale in SampleSalesTable on product.Id equals sale.ProductId into productSales
    select new
    {
        Id = product.Id,
        TotalSales = product.TotalSales + productSales.Sum(sale => sale.Amount)
    };
```

But since in some of the comments you mentioned converting to SQL, most likely you are using some ORM like LinqToSQL, EF or EF Core. In such case the things are even simpler. These ORMs support a so called *navigation properties* which represent the relationships, and when used inside queries are translated to SQL with all the                                                                                                                                                                                                           necessary joins, so you don't need to be bothered with such details and can concentrate on the logic needed to produce the desired result.

If that's the case, the `Product` class would normally have something like

```
public ICollection<Sale> Sales { get; set; }
```

and the query in question would be simple `Select` like this:

```
var query = db.Products
    .Select(product => new
    {
        Id = product.Id,
        TotalSales = product.TotalSales + product.Sales.Sum(sale => sale.Amount)
    });
```

Comment: I'm getting this error `(Unable to create a constant value of type 'Anonymous type'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.)`

Comment: This sounds like EF6 error :) But can't be from any of the above two quite simple queries. Most likely you are doing something else in the real code which is causing that exception.

Answer (score 1):

`LEFT JOIN` with grouping looks like

```
        var query = 
            from product in SampleProductTable
            join sale in SampleSalesTable.GroupBy(c => c.ProductId) 
                 on product.Id equals sale.Key into join1
            from lj in join1.DefaultIfEmpty() // left join 
            select new
            {
                Id = product.Id,
                TotalSales = product.TotalSales + (lj == null ? 0 : lj.Sum(c => c.Amount))
            };
```

[Left join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-left-outer-joins) may return null, so check the potential group, `lj` before trying to sum it. For later c# versions null check could be abbreviated to

```
            TotalSales = product.TotalSales + (lj?.Sum(c => c.Amount) ?? 0)
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/AOaxOI)

Answer (score 0):

In query syntax, Slava's solution should return with the result you're looking for i.e.

```
var querySyntax = (from product in SampleProductTable
    join sale in SampleSalesTable on product.Id equals sale.ProductId into sales
    from subSales in sales.DefaultIfEmpty()
    group subSales by new { product.Id, product.TotalSales }
    into grp
    select new
    {
        grp.Key.Id,
        TotalSales = grp.Sum(s => s.Amount) + grp.Key.TotalSales
    }).ToList();
```

If you have a burning desire to use method syntax for whatever reason, this equivalent LINQ query will also work:

```
var methodSyntax = (SampleProductTable
    .GroupJoin(SampleSalesTable, product => product.Id, sale => sale.ProductId,
        (product, sales) => new {product, sales})
    .SelectMany(s => s.sales.DefaultIfEmpty(), (s, subSales) => new {s, subSales})
    .GroupBy(ss => new {ss.s.product.Id, ss.s.product.TotalSales}, ss => ss.subSales)
    .Select(grp => new {grp.Key.Id, TotalSales = grp.Sum(s => s.Amount) + grp.Key.TotalSales})).ToList();
```